# localStorage.clear() usage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

`localStorage.clear()` seems to behave in a manner that completely wipes all local storage. Local Storage seems to fit my use case, but I'm concerned of the possibility the local storage isn't guaranteed to not be cleared outside of my control.

For example:

My web site has a line of code:

`localStorage.setItem('some', 'data');`

Some other website that is operating in the same browser on another tab has this line of code:

`localStorage.clear();`

If that scenario ever happens, when I go to access `localStorage.getItem('some');`, it will return `null` because someone else ran `localStorage.clear()`.

1. Should we never run `localStorage.clear()`?
2. What is the proper usage of `localStorage.clear()` if I am heavily
   using local storage and don't want to write a ton of code to remove
   items from the local storage individually
   `localStorage.removeItem('item1'); localStorage.removeItem('item2');
   // etc...`
3. Is there some way to prevent items from being removed if someone
   runs `localStorage.clear()` somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to worry, every time you open a new window or tab a new session is created and localStorage refers to the local session of that tab/window which is unique for that domain.

1. Your fine running it, it will only clear your variables
2. If you need to clear everything use feel free to use `localStorage.clear()`
3. Someone else cannot clear your local storage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: So the only way you can get screwed is if you're working on a larger team and someone else runs it within your site. That's understandable.

Answer (score 2):

It is unique per domain. For example the `localStorage` for your domain

`protocol://abc.com` will be different from `protocol://xyz.com`